# How to avoid selecting row in sql server which has special symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to avoid selecting row which has special symbol like mentioned below . [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use range of **ASCII** character as below. `CHAR(n)` returns character value of integer **ASCII** code n

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%['+CHAR(32) +'-'+CHAR(126)+']%' 
OR Name NOT LIKE '%['+CHAR(32) +'-'+CHAR(126)+']%';
```

[**Refer ASCII characters**](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thank you @Mudassir Hasan, your solution worked for me.Only ASCII SUB special character creating problem, so I excluded those records contains ASCII SUB special character using below query.
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%'+CHAR(26)+'%'

Answer (score 2):

You could use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9_-]%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9_-]%';
```

This would select only rows where both `ID` and `Name` columns do *not* contain any special characters.  Special characters here are defined as anything other alphanumeric, underscore, and hyphen.